# Op-amp phase margin issue

Tags: operational-amplifier, stability, phase-margin

I have designed a PMOS-based 2-stage op-amp. While performing an AC analysis to check the stability of the design, the gain obtained is high and positive.

The issue I am facing is the phase margin starting at 0° and moving down. I am confused about the behaviour of the phase margin, shouldn't it start at +180°? Is there a mistake in the testbench?

I have attached the testbench and the output of the AC analysis.

[image: AC ANALYSIS]

[image: OPAMP TESTBENCH]

Comment: It is not the phase margin which should start at -180deg, but the phase shift of the frequency-dependent gain - provided your input signal is injected into the inverting input node. The actual phase margin depends on the feedback path - and is most critical for 100% feedback.

Comment: Yeah its actually phase shift and not the phase margin. I do understand that the phase margin actually depends on the feedback, but still why its initial phase is 0 degree ?

Comment: I think yout input signal works against two inverting transistor stages.

Comment: I got the problem, as mentioned by LvW I was putting my input voltage at the npn-inverting terminal. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Actually is still not a problem if the phase starts from 0 degree, to know the phase margin all we need to do is subtract the gain crossover frequency with 180 degree.

Comment: Can you answer your own question then?